# One DAO access for each request

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, dao

I have to implement one data access( CRUD call ) to the database for each request that arrives at the REST api. What would be the best way to make it threadsafe implementation. 
Presently, for the REST api, I have a request that comes in. And I can add it to a queue. and return . And I can create a consumer thread which polls from the queue.
However, I would appreciate any insights on how to make a database access for the request using a consumer thread, which is threadsafe. I am using spring for DAO access . This is my DAO class.

```
package dao;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementSetter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;

public class UserDAOImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements UserDAO 
{


    @Autowired
    private DriverManagerDataSource datasource;

private void setDataSource(DriverManagerDataSource datasource)
    {
        this.datasource = datasource;
    }

    @Override
      public List<User> getUsers(String userid) {
        //String query;
        String database_name="tennis.";
        String sql = " select distinct ux.id as user_id , ux.first_name, ux.last_name , lvl.rating as rating , photo.filename as file_name"+
                 "  from mytable.user as ux, "+database_name+"profile as pf , "+database_name+"level as lvl, mytable.photo as photo "+
                 "  where "+
                 "  ux.id = pf.user_id  "+
                 "  and ux.id = photo.user_id"+
                 "  and pf.level_id = lvl.id"+
                 "  and ux.id in "+
                 "  (  select  distinct user_id from "+database_name+"profile "+ 
                 "    where "+database_name+"profile.level_id in "+ 
                 "    (select l.id as levelid  "+
                 "  from "+database_name+"level as l "+
                 "  where l.rating  between "+
                 "  ( ( select distinct level.rating "+
                 "      from  "+database_name+"level, "+database_name+"profile "+
                 "      where level.id = profile.level_id and profile.user_id = ?) -?)  "+
                 "  and  "+
                 "    ( ( select distinct level.rating "+
                 "      from  "+database_name+"level, "+database_name+"profile "+
                 "      where level.id = profile.level_id "+
                 "      and profile.user_id = ?)+?) )) ";

        PreparedStatementSetter ps2 = new PreparedStatementSetter() {
        @Override   
        public void setValues(java.sql.PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
            ps.setString(1, userid);
            ps.setInt(2, 1);
            ps.setString(3, userid);
            ps.setInt(4, 1);
        }

        };

        List<User> users = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql,ps2,new RowMapper<User>()
       {

              @Override
              public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException 
              {

                User user = new User();
                user.setUserid(rs.getString(1));
                user.setFirstName(rs.getString(2));
                user.setLastName(rs.getString(3));
                user.setRating( rs.getString(4));
                //user.setPhoto_file_path(rs.getString(5));
                return user;
              }});
        System.out.println(users.size());
      //  for(User user: users)
    //      System.out.println(user);
        return users;

      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is is not clear what your specific concern about thread safety is but if an object holds no state it is, by definition, thread safe.

The only state I can see in your included dao implementation above is the injected data source and the datasource itself should be thread safe as long as transactions and connections are being managed properly at the thread level in spring.

Failing that you could make your dao prototype scoped and inject it using a java.inject.Provider by defining a ProviderCreatingFactoryBean. That would have some performance implications however.